# How to update MOTD regularly?

Tags: cron, motd

Every week there's a new work log/to-do list at work. There's a `todo` script which can be used to extract my own to-do items from that. Currently this is called in `~/.bash_aliases_local`, which is sourced from `~/.bash_aliases`. Rather than parsing the log every time I start another shell, I'd like to use the standard MOTD (message of the day) functionality. This would involve updating a static file with the to-do list on a weekly basis:

```
@weekly update-motd
```

The resulting static text file should be printed every time I start an interactive Bash shell. What's the standard way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to have the message displayed every time you open up a new terminal (under an X session), then `motd` is not the right place. It is executed by the `login` program - this happens when you log in on a real `tty` (or via `ssh` for example).

For terminal sessions, I believe the only universal way is to run `cat somefile` at the end of your shell's startup file: either personal (i.e. `~/.bashrc` `~/.zshrc` etc.) or global (under `/etc` - see your shell's manpage for details). Generally, I'm afraid there isn't a "standard" way of doing this in case of terminal emulator sessions.

Comment: Seems that .bashrc is not right place too. There are ~/.bash_login and ~/.bash_logout files . They're much better for OP purpose.

Comment: @Rush `.bash_login` only read if bash is a login shell (and even then most people have `.bash_profile` instead). It would be of no help here, as the question is about all interactive shells. `.bashrc` is exactly the right file for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

1. create `/etc/update-motd.d/`
2. place the script there, with format 00script (no .sh)

it will show up in every login

all details are here

https://ownyourbits.com/2017/04/05/customize-your-motd-login-message-in-debian-and-ubuntu/